# JSONSchema to validate JSON based on Enum value

Tags: json, amazon-s3, aws-glue, jsonschema

I Have a JSON and Need to Create JSONSchema to Validate it.

Use case:  On the Selection of one of the services "Glue" or "S3" it should validate one or more resources that have **action** as prefix "/glue" or "/s3".
it also validates the correct input resources and their properties.
one or more resources can be possible in the request JSON.

```
{
    "service": [
        "Glue",
        "S3"
    ],
    "resources": [
        {
            "action": "/glue/list",
            "tags": [
                "glueall"
            ]
        },
        {
            "action": "/glue/get/db",
            "tags": [
                "gluedb"
            ],
            "databaseName": "example"
        },
        {
            "action": "/s3/list",
            "tags": [
                "s3all"
            ]
        },
        {
            "action": "/s3/get/bucket",
            "tags": [
                "s3bucket"
            ],
            "bucketName": "example"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you share all the requirements?  which properties are required for each type?

Answer (score 1):

This covers only two use cases:

This is not based on enum value as requested in the subject line. If you need that, this can be modified accordingly

- if `action` starts with `/glue` and ends with `db`, then `dataBaseName` is `required`
- if `action` starts with `/s3` and ends with `bucket` then `bucketName` is `required`

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["service", "resources"],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "service": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["action", "tags"],
                "properties": {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "pattern": "^\\/"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "uniqueItems": true,
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "properties": {
                                "action": {
                                    "pattern": "^\\/s3.*\\/bucket$"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "required": [
                                "bucketName"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "properties": {
                                "action": {
                                    "pattern": "^\\/glue.*\\/db$"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "required": [
                                "databaseName"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```